# Do airlines have substantially different policies regarding adverse weather conditions?

Tags: air-travel

I've now experienced twice sitting at an airport, seeing flights being cancelled left and right due to adverse weather, with only flights operated by one airline (the same in both cases) remaining (luckily for me, that included my own flight each time). The problem was always the local weather at the airport, once a typhoon in Tokyo, once fog in Cardiff.

This left me wondering whether this was just coincidence, or whether there are substantial differences regarding what kind of weather airlines are willing to fly in.

Comment: Other things to consider: some airlines may have incoming flights cancelled and have no planes or crew members to fly; some airlines have special rights at certain airports for prioritized slot allocation when there is a limited capacity due to bad weather; airports and airlines calculate expected loss and this can differ depending on the routes and the hub model used etc.

Comment: Different aircraft have different rules (on wind/gust speed, wet runway lengths, etc.). And different airlines have different company rules (always more strict then manufacturer limits). A stranded plane (because worsening condition, so no more able to depart) can have more impact on some airlines (compared to others).

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Different aircraft have different rules. E.g. some are able to cope with more wind/gusts. But also the required runway length may become important. That length changes with weather. With snow or heavy rain the planes may need more runway, which may not be available.

Then airlines have different rules. Manufacturer set a limit, but airlines usually are stricter. Note: such limit depends on aircraft and airline.

Then the aircraft and crew may be a limit. With fog, you may require autolanding (the CAT II/III red signal you may see near runways), but this requires certified aircraft (not just model) and pilots.

Pilots may have different opinions. A pilot new to an airport may prefer to choose an alternate, if the airport is also considered tricky with bad weather.

Operation reasons: a stranded aircraft may be more problematic for some airlines (maybe with home base away), so some airlines may not risk to have a grounded plane.

Operation 2: crew have restriction on number of hours they can operate (day and long term). Delays may block some pilots to fly (or fly back).

Note: you should consider also the route and alternate airports, and restriction on airports. With bad weather, the destination airport may have huge delays, so accepting less planes (and this may depend on routes). Also the delays may affect some restriction on destination airport.